# Having troubles to understanding differentiation of multivariable vectors

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

What doesn't seem to get around my head is how differentiation with vectors work. I have seen my (physics) teacher differentiate the unitary vector $\vec{u_r}$ using the following: $$\frac{d\vec{u_r}}{dt}=\frac{\partial \vec{u_r}}{\partial r}\dot{r}+\frac{\partial \vec{u_r}}{\partial \theta}\dot \theta+\frac{\partial \vec{u_r}}{\partial \phi}\dot \phi$$ for the  unitary vectors for the spherical coordinates, which depend on those three variables $\vec{u_r}=\vec{u_r}(r(t),\theta(t),\phi(t))$. But then for the position vector itself, $\vec{r}=r\vec{u_r}$ (by definition), he used the following to differentiate: $$\frac{d\vec r}{dt}=\dot r\vec{u_r}+\dot{\vec{u_r}}r$$ How?? I know that the chain rule for multivariable ***scalar*** functions like $f=f(x(t),y(t))$ is $\dot f=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dt}$ but is that rule also comparable and usable for the ***vectorial*** functions? One thing that really helps me is the tree drawing of the derivatives and it's variables, to see if I have to add or not, is there a vectorial function version of that?

Comment: This is the product rule; both $r$ and $\vec{u_r}$ depend on $t$.

Comment: @user170231 yeah but why does $\vec r$ and $\vec u_r$ differentiate differently? In one they used the product rule and in the other one they seem to have used another weird chain rule, I'm asking for that

Comment: $r(t)$ is not the same function as $\vec r(t)$, which is defined as $r$ times $\vec u_r$. You don't need any special rules to different $r$, that's just $\dot r$. But you do need to use the chain rule to different $\vec r$ by virtue of $\vec u_r$'s dependence on $r(t),\theta(t),\phi(t)$.

Comment: @user170231 I promise I'm trying to understand, I know the vector of $r$ isn't the same as it's module, and I see what you say about $\vec{u_r}$'s dependence as I already mentioned, but for me, $\vec{r}$ depends as well on $r(t)$, no? Oh, so as it only depends on $r(t)$, you can do the product rule on $\vec r$?




 So say, that $\vec r$ depended on $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$, then $\vec{\dot r}$ would be differentiated the same way as $\vec{u_r}$?

Comment: > Why does $\vec r$ and $\vec u_r$ differentiate differently ?    $\vec r$ and $\vec u_r$ are not the same. Why do you want their derivates to be the same ?

Comment: @Digitallis because both are vectors so I assumed both needed to be integrated with that chain rule, but now I'm reorganising my brain into why not, is it because $\vec r$ depends on $r(t)$ exclusively? If it depended on $r(t)$ and $\theta(t)$, would we need to use the chain rule the same way we did with $\vec{u_r}$?

Comment: $\vec r$ *does* depend on $r$ in a sense, but you're asked for the derivative w.r.t. to $t$, not w.r.t. some function of $t$. Try using the definition of the derivative to express $\dfrac{d\vec r}{dt}$ and see if a derivative w.r.t. to $r$ pops out,$$\frac{d\vec r}{dt} = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{\vec r(t+h)-\vec r(t)}h=\cdots$$

Comment: @user170231 which defn? the limit definition of a derivative? Also, I know it is w.r.t to $t$ but it is also w.r.t. on the $\vec{u_r}$, both cases are differentiating wrt to $t$, I'm not following how is this relevant to my question regarding why both derivatives are different

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your concern correctly, you are asking why $\dot{\vec r}$ doesn't seem to have a chain-rule form similar to

$$\frac{d\vec u_r}{dt} = \frac{\partial\vec u_r}{\partial r} \, \dot r + \frac{\partial\vec u_r}{\partial\theta} \,  \dot\theta + \frac{\partial\vec u_r}{\partial\phi}\,\dot\phi$$

That is, perhaps you expected to see the expression

$$\dot{\vec r} = \frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial r} \, \dot r + \frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial\theta}\,\dot\theta + \frac{\partial\vec r}{\partial\phi}\,\dot\phi$$

and that would be correct. Your instructor has provided an equivalent form.

Since $\vec r:=r\,\vec u_r$, we use the product rule to compute the partial derivatives,

$$\dot{\vec r} = \left(\vec u_r + r\,\frac{\partial\vec u_r}{\partial r}\right) \dot r + r\,\frac{\partial\vec u_r}{\partial \theta}\, \dot\theta + r\,\frac{\partial\vec u_r}{\partial \phi}\, \dot \phi$$

then rearrange terms as

$$\dot{\vec r} = \vec u_r \,\dot r + r \left(\frac{\partial\vec u_r}{\partial r}\,\dot r + \frac{\partial\vec u_r}{\partial \theta}\,\dot\theta + \frac{\partial\vec u_r}{\partial \phi}\,\dot\phi\right)$$

and this is of course equivalent to $\vec u_r\,\dot r+\dot{\vec u_r}\,r$, as per the product rule.

---

P.S. To my point about using the definition of the derivative, we have

$$\begin{align*}
\dot{\vec r} &= \lim_{h\to0} \frac{r(t+h) \vec u_r(t+h) - r(t)\vec u_r(t)}h \\
&= \lim_{h\to0} \left(\frac{r(t+h)\vec u_r(t+h) - r(t+h)\vec u_r(t)}h + \frac{r(t+h)\vec u_r(t) - r(t)\vec u_r(t)}h\right) \\
&= r(t)\dot{\vec u_r}(t) + \dot r(t)\vec{u_r}(t)
\end{align*}$$

which is the typical way one establishes the product rule. Note the absence of any derivatives w.r.t. $r$.